# Magento 2: How to Show method if not applicable Country Wise?

Tags: magento2, error, shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I'm using DHL Shipping Method. I have set `Show Method if Not Applicable` to `Yes`.

`Displayed Error Message` will be displayed, when it's applicable.

I would like to show this Error Message by Specific Country.

Example: If it's Singapore then this message will be not displayed. For other countries, it will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service" : "Custom_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service"
    }
  }
};
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model\shipping-service.js**

```
/*global define*/
define(
        [
            'jquery', // For jQuery Added
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote', // For Quote Added
            'ko',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver'
        ],
        function ($, quote, ko, checkoutDataResolver) {
            "use strict";
            var shippingRates = ko.observableArray([]);
            return {
                isLoading: ko.observable(false),
                /**
                 * Set shipping rates
                 *
                 * @param ratesData
                 */
                setShippingRates: function (ratesData) {

                   // START TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGE FOR DHL IF SG
                    var address = quote.shippingAddress();

                    $.each(ratesData, function (k, v) {
                        if(v.method_code == null && v.carrier_code == 'dhl' && v.error_message != '' && address.countryId == 'SG'){
                            ratesData.splice(k , 1);
                        }
                    });
                    // STOP TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGE FOR DHL IF SG

                    shippingRates(ratesData);
                    shippingRates.valueHasMutated();
                    checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingRates(ratesData);
                },

                /**
                 * Get shipping rates
                 *
                 * @returns {*}
                 */
                getShippingRates: function () {
                    return shippingRates;
                }
            };
        }
);
```

If someone has solution on PHP side then it would be great.