# Magento 2: How to get current shipping address country in shipping.html?

Tags: magento2, custom, shipping-methods, quote, shipping-address

How to get current shipping country in below file?

**magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html**

```
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    -------- HERE ----------
</li>
```

Comment: From this what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @KeyurShah Actually i want to hide error message on basis of country if not applicable. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148788/magento-2-how-to-show-method-if-not-applicable-country-wise So looking for alternatives