# Magento 2 checkout page how to get country_id from selected shipping addresses?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, jquery

How to get **country id/country name** from selected shipping address in the checkout page.

lets assume if the customer has multiple shipping addresses,
based on the shipping address choose, if country name is not **United States** we want to display some Text message on the top. (International Custom Duties........)
[image]

for this i have followed @Sarfaraz bheda answer for creating hook.js

[Magento2 - How to trigger onchange event on Country/region in Shipping Address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175806/magento2-how-to-trigger-onchange-event-on-country-region-in-shipping-address)

thanks

Comment: I have updated my code to resolve 1 issue when customer is logged in.

Comment: Regarding saved address, you can add dependency of `'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',` and get customer current details.

Comment: To get shipping address information you can add dependency of `Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote` https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148788/magento-2-how-to-show-method-if-not-applicable-country-wise

Comment: did you resolve the issue. can you post the answer if you did? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Include quote js like

```
    define([
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ])
```

in custom js. And try

```
    var countryId = quote.shippingAddress().countryId;
    var country = countryData()[countryId].name;
```

it will give you country ID

Comment: Its not working for me, can you show us how you did it please

Comment: I did this in custom store pickup js view.Which is included through component.

Comment: would you be able to show me?

Comment: Please refer link,                                    
      https://marketplace.magento.com/cybage-storepickup.html

Comment: What is this? This is not what i want
thanks for the help @anjali

Comment: Above shared link is the the magento extension url where you will find the way to get country_id

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @anjali-patil for giving a huge hint, I'll try to post here what he meant in more detail.

In your your component js file there is most likely a `define(['A', 'B', 'C'], (A, B, C) => ...)` call which is an [AMD](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs) way to require files your script depends on. Here you can add a dependency to `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'` (if not already). [`quote.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/quote.js) file provides you the info about the current quote, including shipping address (via `shippingAddress()` method).

Example:

```
define([
    'some/module.js', 'some/otherModule.js', 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], ( someModule     ,  someOtherModule     ,  quote) => {
    console.log(quote.shippingAddress());
})
```

It will output something like this:

```
{
    "customerAddressId": "1",
    "countryId": "LV",
    "regionId": "368",
    "regionCode": "Aizputes novads",
    "region": "Aizputes novads",
    "customerId": "1",
    "street": ["Maskavas 379, 33"],
    "telephone": "456456",
    "postcode": "LV-1063",
    "city": "Riga",
    "firstname": "Artur",
    "lastname": "Klesun"
}
```

Comment: `console.log(quote.shippingAddress());` return `null`